# Regex Lookahead not matching as expected

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a small java program to do a bit of database cleanup where I need to pull dates out of large blocks of text when they appear in the same sentence as certain keywords and I'm getting some strange behavior that I can't figure out. For instance, the following regex:

```
"(?=.*(due|submit|deadline)[^\\d]*)"
+ "(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)"
+ "\\s*(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(th|rd|nd|st)*,*\\s*((19|20)\\d\\d)"
```

Doesn't match this:

"Must be submitted, before twelve o'clock noon on wednesday, june 19, 2013, at which time it will be read."

although the keyword `"submit"` occurs before the date. If I take out the lookahead, the string matches. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: word `submitted` is not in your regex pattern.

Comment: the pattern for date is also not in standard way. why are you checking for `th|rd|nd|st`?

Comment: @Braj That shouldn't matter, right? 'submitted' contains 'submit'

Comment: Regex from your question will not compile. Also you need to show us how you are using the real one.

Comment: @Pshemo fixed, missed parenthesis when I pasted it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you forgot that look-ahead is zero-width which means regex cursor will be set at place where look-ahead started checking its condition. This means that part matching

```
+ "(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)"
+ "\\s*(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(th|rd|nd|st)*,*\\s*((19|20)\\d\\d)";
```

needs to exist right after place which look-ahead started checking.

To solve this problem you need to add `.*?` before `(january|...` to let months exist little farther place checked by look-ahead and matched (like place right before `due`).

Also to avoid using look-ahead in multiple times make it only look for match right after start of your String by adding `^` at start.

So your final regex can look like

```
    String regex = "^(?=.*(due|submit|deadline)[^\\d]*)"
            + ".*?(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)"
            + "\\s*(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(th|rd|nd|st)*,*\\s*((19|20)\\d\\d)";
```

[**Look-ahead demo**](http://ideone.com/DcQ8f2)

---

Actually I am not sure why are you even using look-ahead. Wouldn't something like

```
    String regex = "(due|submit|deadline).*?"
            + "(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)"
            + "\\s*(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(th|rd|nd|st)*,*\\s*((19|20)\\d\\d)";
```

also do what you want?

[**No look-ahead demo**](http://ideone.com/ca22cl)

Comment: I'm using a lookahead because I only want to capture the date and not the rest of the string, but that's an easy fix from here. Thank you

Comment: @user2559503 I am glad it worked out for you. Judging by fact that you are familiar with look-ahead I assume that you also know what is the difference between `.*` and `.*?`, but just in case you don't, read about greedy and reluctant quantifiers.